# Why am I getting a null pointer access?

Tags: java, eclipse

Why am I getting a

```
Null pointer access: The variable versionFromInputStream can only be null at this location
```

Error?
Is that because the IDE doesn't know about the read method?

```
byte[] versionFromInputStream = null;

if (input.read(versionFromInputStream, 0, 3) != 3)
{
    throw new NetworkException();
}

double version = Double.parseDouble(versionFromInputStream.toString());
```

Comment: No, it's because it's clearly null: `versionFromInputStream = null;`.

Comment: Wha is input ? Please provide details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you've got a couple of things going on here that aren't right

```
        byte[] versionFromInputStream = null; // you should initialize this like = new byte[2048]; because..
        
        if (input.read(versionFromInputStream, 0, 3) != 3) // because here you are trying to read into this byte array. And because it hasn't been initialized, you are getting the exception
        {
            throw new NetworkException();
        }
        
        double version = Double.parseDouble(versionFromInputStream.toString()); // this isn't going to work either. byte[].toString is the same as Object.toString - it just prints out the location of the object in virtual memory, which isn't what you want
```

Comment: Oops, I did not initialize the variable, :/
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [`read`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte%5B%5D,int,int)) method of a stream expects an existing byte array with enough space to be passed. Also, the conversion of bytes to String ought to be done via the [`String(byte[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(byte%5B%5D)) constructor.

In this case, you are reading three bytes, so the following ought to suffice:

```
 byte[] versionFromInputStream = new byte[3];
        
 if (input.read(versionFromInputStream, 0, 3) != 3)
 {
     throw new NetworkException();
 }
        
 double version = Double.parseDouble(new String(versionFromInputStream));
```

From a design standpoint, you may want to avoid sending strings over a network as it's inefficient. As long as you have control over both the sender and the receiver, a [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInputStream.html)/`DataOutputStream` will let you natively read and write integers to the stream, without the overhead of reading bytes and converting them to strings to be parsed. As a quick example showing the receive side (with an integer version):

```
DataInputStream dataInput = new DataInputStream(input);
int version = dataInput.readInt();
```

You'd need to adapt the sender to use a `DataOutputStream` accordingly.

Comment: It isn't clear that the data being received is a String, and byte[].toString() doesn't interpret the byte data as String (use new String(byte[] instead). And DataInput/OutputStreams are bad because they are only Java compatible, and you CAN send integers over plain input/output streams. (Especially now that they've rectified the Endian problem)

Comment: @ControlAltDel I've edited the remarks about the string constructor. The Data{Input|Output} stream is a suggestion to the OP, that they are encouraged to evaluate for themselves based on their use-case (in an ideal world everyone would just use protocol buffers|flat buffers|whatnot for wire serialization, but that's outside of the scope of this answer). In the end, for a Java<->Java socket, the Data*Stream remain a convenient option for simple communication.